# Why pray what does it do?

Tags: prayer

Is prayer just saying things that I believe? Or so others feel good? I need to know the importance of prayer. It is not clear to me in Scripture.

Comment: Prayer is as mysterious as God Himself.  Accept that we are instructed to pray!

Comment: Please see the Tour and the Help (below, bottom left) as to the purpose and the functioning of this _hermeneutic_ site, especially as regards raising biblical topics for discussion , which is off-topic as we cannot practice hermeneutic analysis if there is no text introduced in question for us to analyse.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, Prayer is you talking to God. Whether by you thanking Him, Praising Him, asking help of Him for yourself or others or just saying anything, like any concerns you have or just sharing your feelings or thoughts. Eph 6:18 Phil 4:6

Answer (score 1):

In my oppinion there are fundamentally 2 elements is a prayer: questions and statements.
Therefore, what a prayer does is: ask things and state things.

The further effects of these questions and statements depend on a lot of things like who, what and how.

Answer (score 0):

"Prayer" | Tefillah (תפילה) derives from "Evaluate" | Pallel (פלל).

- פלל - **to invoke a judge**. [[Klein Dictionary](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.9.26?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Klein_Dictionary%2C_%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%9C_%E1%B4%B5%E1%B4%B5.1&lang2=bi&lookup2=%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%9C&w2=Lexicon&lang3=en), Carta Jerusalem; 1st edition, 1987]

By self-evaluating, we either : [#1] respectfully acknowledge the Source of our benefits [Tehillim 121/Devarim 6:4];  [#2] humbly acknowledge the need to improve our kindness and truth [Mishlei 16:6].

Answer (score 0):

Prayer is a way of keeping yourself connected to God; another, accompanying way is a contemplation of divine truth, but this contemplation is also contributive to a deeper prayer for more divine things. For instance, a sportsman can pray for a victory in a tournament, but a philosopher can pray that such a transient thing as sports glory may not creep into his heart and mind as an object of desire.

Also prayers can influence others: for instance, one can pray for health of others and if God wills it, He will grant it.